# How to use linq to print variable from object in comma separated?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list like below which has some data in it. `Client` class has `clientId` variable in it.

```
var clients = new List<Client>();
```

I want to print all those `clientIds` from `clients` object using linq efficiently. Basically I want it to be logged like this in comma separated way where each of those numbers are `clientId`:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

How can I use linq in my below log?

```
Console.WriteLine($"All clientIds ");
```

Comment: Use string join : var clients = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            string output = string.Join(",", clients);

Comment: @jdweng `String.Join` and `Select`: `string output = string.Join(",", clients.Select(c => c.clientId));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you just select the property you need into an array with linq and then you use join on the array.

```
var allClients = string.Join(",", clients.Select(c=> c.clientId));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void Main()
{
    var clients = new List<Client>
    {
        new Client { ClientId = 101 },
        new Client { ClientId = 1 },
        new Client { ClientId = 4 },
        new Client { ClientId = 24 },
        new Client { ClientId = 2 },
    };
    
    string result = string.Join<int>(",", clients.Select(x => x.ClientId));
    
    Console.WriteLine($"All clientIds {result}");
}

class Client
{
    public int ClientId;
}
```